# can't return obj from angular factory

Tags: angularjs, factory

this is my factory service.

```
(function() {
    var appfactory = angular.module("RoyalApp");
    appfactory.factory('packService', packService);

    packService.$inject = ['varsService', '$http'];

    function packService(varsService, $http) {

        var packages = {

            getPackages: function() {
                $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:63666/api/Package?customer_id=" + varsService.dataObj._id
                }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function myError(response) {

                });
            }
        }
        return packages;
    }
})();
```

in my controller i use this to store them inside the controllers scope

```
var vm = this;
vm.packages = packService.packages.getPackages;
```

also tried this

```
vm.packages = packService.packages.getPackages();
```

i have no errors in chrome console and my http respone is correct .i simply can't return the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```javascript
packService.getPackages().then(function(packages) {
    vm.packages = packages;
});
```

And note that `getPackages` must return promise:

```
getPackages: function() {
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:63666/api/Package?customer_id=" + varsService.dataObj._id
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {

    });
}
```

Couple of notes. `packService`'s public API contains single method `getPackages` - this is what you need to call. Then it returns a promise object you use to provide a callback (with `then` method) to be invoked when data is loaded.

Comment: i tried it didn't work maybe i miss something. thanks for the time spend . i am thinking of pausing my app to do some study on factory's and services before i continue.

Comment: i added a function that i had in my controller which worked (had different scope variables). for a reason i wanted to take the data from a service and not from a http call inside my controller. so when i transfered my function in the service even thought my http call was working i couldn't pass the response  in service a variable which  i could read in my controller . perhaps i am approaching the hole manner wrong .

Comment: Post the code that was failing. I gave you a solution how it should be done. Making http requests from controller directly is not a very good idea and should be avoided. Don't give up, set up a minimal demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vAHi03zzqYUO4eGwxUOU so could help, it's something very simple.

Comment: after a short break i start project again . i rewrote my controller and factory according to your answers and i finally manage  to make it work. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Feel free to accept the answer and close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope' 'packService', function($scope, packService){
          var vm = this;
          packService.getPackages().then(function(packages) {
            vm.packages = packages;
          });
      }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put names in anonymous function delegates. Remove 'mySuccess' & 'myError' and try again (don't forget to handle the returns as promises in your controller as mentioned in the answers before mine).

```
getPackages: function() {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:63666/api/Package?customer_id=" + varsService.dataObj._id
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function (response) {

            });
        }
```